# how to create an array in a helper and then loop through in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a poll, and I've created a helper to return a JSON object of all the results which works like so:

```
module PollVotesHelper
  def poll_results_json(poll)

    @poll_results = Array.new

    @poll_results << {
      :total_votes => poll.poll_votes.length,
      :options => poll.poll_options.collect { |poll_option|
        {
          :id => poll_option.id,
          :title => poll_option.title,
          :vote_percentage => '33%',          
          :vote_count => poll_option.poll_votes.length
        }
      }
    }
    @poll_results.to_json
  end

end
```

Then in the view I want to call it and loop through the options and output the title, etc...

```
<% poll_results_json(@poll)['options'].each do |poll_option| %>
 <%= poll_option['id'] %>
 <%= poll_option['title'] %>
 <%= poll_option['vote_percentage'] %>
 <%= poll_option['vote_count'] %>
<% end %>
```

The view is erroring. What's the right way to loop through the resulting JSON object?

Thanks

Comment: Error 2011-07-23 12:37:39 -0700 ERROR (SampleJob#perform): can't convert String into Integer - (ActionView::Template::Error)
.....html.erb:81:in `[]'

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use a hash and not an array, since you're storing key/value pairs?

Comment: And why do you need JSON here?

Comment: JSON to send back to the browser. I need this type of object in multiple ways

Comment: Is there a better way to build it that would work as a hash and also let me output via json?

Comment: I'm not sure, but just try a hash instead of an array and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you want to iterate through **JSON** data, not a **Ruby** array. This is because `to_json` just returns a Ruby **string** with valid JSON inside. So instead of converting your whole `Poll` objects into JSON, you should just return the values as JSON:

```
<% @poll.poll_options.each do |poll_option| %>
  <%= poll_option.id.to_json %>
  <%= poll_option.title.to_json %>
  <%= '33%'.to_json %>
  <%= poll_option.poll_votes.length.to_json %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what? not sure you are saying not use a helper? I need the helper to computer the outputs

Comment: I also need this output in JSON for other methods, so staying DRY by using the one JSON output throughout the app makes things clean

Comment: You're converting your data from Ruby to JSON, but to use this data in your view and accessing it via Ruby it has to be Ruby. Your helper just returns a **String** (with JSON) inside. You cannot access JSON data directly in Ruby.

Comment: So instead of using my first solution (which is I think the best :P) have you tried using just `<%= poll_results_json(@poll) %>`. This will work since you're just printing a String into your view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your are pushing Hash into an Array(@poll_results).Instead try something like

```
module PollVotesHelper
 def poll_results_json(poll)

  @poll_results = {
    :total_votes => poll.poll_votes.length,
    :options => poll.poll_options.collect { |poll_option|
    {
      :id => poll_option.id,
      :title => poll_option.title,
      :vote_percentage => '33%',          
      :vote_count => poll_option.poll_votes.length
    }
  }
}
  @poll_results.to_json
 end
end
```

The value returned from the method will be a string.first you need to parse json to process it.

```
in your view try like 
<% JSON.parse(poll_results_json(@poll))['options'].each do |poll_option| %>
  <%= poll_option['id'] %>
  <%= poll_option['title'] %>
  <%= poll_option['vote_percentage'] %>
  <%= poll_option['vote_count'] %>
<% end %>
```